# How to update XML file with ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have xml storage with in this format

```
<Contacts>
     <Contact>
         <![CDATA["Some HTML"]]>
     </Contact>
     <Contact>
         <![CDATA["Some HTML"]]>
     </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

I am using XMLHttpRequest to read the data and put it inside a "div" on the page. Now I make some changes on it via JavaScript and I would like to know how can I update the changes made back to the XML file from where I took the data.
I've been googling a lot but I have problems understanding those forums because they are not describing examples similar like mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ajax call which you give the xml data.  You can then save the data using simplexml http://nl.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php or using http://nl.php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php

Answer (score 0):

Leave the "retrieving" your XML on JavaScript, and "saving changes" on PHP. Using jQuery you just `$.get()` your XML file, and when you save it (let it be `.click`, `.live('click')` etc.)
you `$.post()` strings you wrote in some input to something like `save_xml.php`. There are some tools for working with XML files in PHP. If you get on well with Smarty, I advise you to keep sort of `my_xml_template.tpl` , which after `smarty->fetch` you save in a file with `file_put_contents()`. Cheers.